# Cannot view the streamlit app in browser when running through docker

Tags: windows, docker, streamlit

I am trying to run streamlit through docker. I am referring the example at this https://github.com/domoritz/streamlit-docker. Following are the details of my system:

```
Operating System: Windows 10 Home

System type: 64-bit operating system

Docker version 19.03.1
```

I executed the `docker-compose run streamlit black src/` command and got the following output:

```
reformatted src/main.py All done! ✨  ✨ 1 file reformatted.
```

Next I executed the `docker-compose up` command and got the following output:

```
Starting streamlit-docker-master_streamlit_1 ... done 
Attaching to streamlit-docker-master_streamlit_1 
streamlit_1 | 
streamlit_1 | You can now view your Streamlit app in your browser. 
streamlit_1 | 
streamlit_1 | Network URL: http://172.19.0.2:8501
streamlit_1  |   External URL: http://64.121.102.75:8501
```

But I can’t view any app output in the browser. I see the above output on docker terminal for infinite time until I press `Ctrl + C`. When I try to open the link: `http://localhost:8501/?name=main`, it says the site can’t be reached.

Can someone please help me resolve this?

Thank you

Comment: can you try with `http://172.19.0.2:8501` or `http://64.121.102.75:8501`  or you can also try with virtual machine IP in window `docker-machine ip default`

Comment: I checked my virtual machine IP window and tried that IP and it worked! Thank you so much for the guidance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If localhost does not work then You can try with virtual machine IP in window

```
docker-machine ip default
```